# Hooking Caliburn.Micro WindowManager up within Excel

Tags: c#, wpf, excel, caliburn.micro

I have a problem that is similar to that posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17519903/setting-caliburn-iwindowmanagers-owner-property-to-excel-with-handle-hwnd). I have posted before about using Caliburn.Micro in an Excel Document customization where the WPF controls are on an `ActionsPane` without receiving much help.

I currently have this working by placing the `ShellView` user control onto the design surface of the `ActionsPane` inside the `ElementHost`. Most things work as normal with Caliburn.Micro, however I do not get any `Activate` or `Deactivate` events because I haven't got a reference to a Caliburn.Micro `WindowManager`.

If I create a new window manager and use it to show a window using `ShowWindow`, then the window appears as a completely separate window (not in the `ActionPane`) however I do get Activate/Deactivate events.

Is there some way to attach Caliburn.Micro's Window manager to the `ActionPane` within Excel. I already have a MEF Bootstrapper passing false to `BootstrapperBase`.

Regards
Alan

Comment: Why don't you inject the `IWindowManager` into the view-model of the `ShellView` ? I don't see your exact problem, if you could add some more details or explanation I might be able to help you further, and by the way are you using view-first or model-first navigation ?

Comment: @Sniffer Take a look at the answer I gave to my own problem https://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/discussions/454585. Maybe this will give you the extra info you need. If you have a working solution I'd love to know how to do this.

Comment: From what I saw, it looks like your problem is solved, so unless you need something else or something is not working I am not gonna add anything.

Comment: The method I used to get it working inside an ActionsPane doesn't generate any Activate/Deactivate events because there's no WindowManager hooked up, which is why I referenced your thread. I want to know how to get the WindowManager to be the ActionsPane inside Excel.

Comment: I am kind of busy these days, I will try to reply to you as soon as I can.